# Docker messed with local django/postgres projects. Can't run project on localhost

Tags: django, postgresql

I stocked at postgresql/django issue. After attempt of running the localhost server got the following error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.17.0.1", database "closerdb", SSL off
```

According to many similar issues and answers last lines at pg_hba.conf look this way:

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                md5
local   replication     postgres                                trust
host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     postgres        172.17.0.1              trust
host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

I have restarted postgres after editing .conf file, but error remains. I supposed that it was cause by docker installation, because normally django project has to run on loclahost(127.0.0.1) and  172.17.0.1 is a default docker ip.

How to fix all that and avoid such problems in future?

EDIT: django database settings. worked fine previously  before installing docker:

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'closerdb',
        # 'HOST': '/tmp/mysql.sock',
        # 'PORT': '8000',            
        # 'HOSTNAME': '',
        'USER': 'thekotik',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your django just wants to connect to a database called `closerdb`. In this case the corresponding `pg_hba.conf` entry should look like that:

```
host    closerdb     postgres        172.17.0.1              trust
```

From the [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html):

> The value replication specifies that the record matches if a replication connection is requested (note that replication connections do not specify any particular database). Otherwise, this is the name of a specific PostgreSQL database

I also want to point out that you should use `trust` carefully depending on your environment, because:

> Allow the connection unconditionally. This method allows anyone that can connect to the PostgreSQL database server to login as any PostgreSQL user they wish, without the need for a password or any other authentication.

Comment: django project must run on 127.0.0.1 so I deleted all host lines and added this one to .conf : host     closerdb        postgres        127.0.0.1             trust

Comment: The error indicates, that the connection is established to the socket `172.17.0.1:5432` - if you dislike that, you should change your setup.

Comment: I'am sorry, how exactly?)

Comment: To answer the question, you should post your docker setup. But currently your postgres runs in a container with IP `172.17.0.1` and django knows about that - tries to connect there, but is not allowed to. If you want it running without changing the setup and django configuration - use the pg_hba.conf entry from my answer.

Comment: but what docker setup has to do with it? how do I tell django project(which is not in container/docker and must run on localhost) to connect not to docker postgres but to os x installed postgres and run normally on localhost?

Comment: ok - which application runs where? may you add your django settings to the question?

Comment: well, django application is in os x User/user folder, and docker is installed somewhere in applications. the idea that conflict is caused by docker is just because 172.17.0.1 is it's default ip, and django application outside docker must run on  127.0.0.1. there is also postgres inside docker, but the very idea of docker doesn't allow such conflicts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136289/discussion-between-vinand-and-dahrens).